# If you had to communicate Africa in one sound effect one second long, what would it be?

Tags: africa

I'm working on a music video right now which is more like a short film and I need something that communicates Africa (there is a cut-away of someone dancing in Africa for a second while the song expands out into an international hit). The director wants a sound effect that communicates Africa to be placed there.

I've tried a few animals, just not jiving. It's for a jive band and there is a trombone player - maybe I'll place in a trombone lick that mimics an elephant blow.

Any ideas of a sound effect that communicates Africa in less than a second?

Answer (score 3):

vuvuzela.

(just kidding)

Answer (score 2):

maybe a quick drum roll on a djembe or conga drum

Comment: I second a tribal drum roll paced to tempo of the picture or the rest of the music. Maybe a single large African Drum hit with some bass to it similar to a large Taiko drum for a heavy impact and a higher pitched Djembe or Congo roll on top of it for an accent.

Answer (score 2):

Survivorman has a great commercial bump-in/bump-out sfx hit that has an "Africa" sound to it. This just happens to be a clip from the Africa episode, but it's in all of his episodes. Some inspiration, maybe. [Click Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1nu8EiEP8I&feature=player_detailpage#t=517s)

Answer (score 1):

african music, where they show a picture of a safari with a giraffe, the bug noise also, and maybe an elephant or sounds of chains or a special drum or chant, shakers

Answer (score 1):

a short african chant...

Answer (score 1):

May be a Tribal chant phrase accompanied with a drum roll/hit might work. For me Africa is more about people

Answer (score 1):

I hear either a djembe or a kalimba. Good luck with the project.

Comment: ... or clapping.

Answer (score 1):

I hear a short chant (more like a single shout) mixed with with a drum roll.

Answer (score 1):

i can imagine a Djembe, and some other percussions with a delay and some tribal chants and with ethnic instruments

Answer (score 1):

I hear hakuna matata